# The site configured at this address does not contain the requested file

Tags: github-pages

I have made the setup for jekyll and pushed my repo here https://github.com/vamsipavanmahesh/rubyhive. When I visit `https://vamsipavanmahesh.github.io/rubyhive` I get this

```
The site configured at this address does not contain the requested file.

If this is your site, make sure that the filename case matches the URL.
For root URLs (like http://example.com/) you must provide an index.html file.

Read the full documentation for more information about using GitHub Pages.
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I have not enabled github pages in the repo settings. you need to set the source as master